# How to add the values ​in an array of objects depending on the date value of each object

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
[{start_date: "2022-12-05T04:00:00Z" ,distance: 1000, time: 3600} 
,{start_date: "2022-02-07T04:00:00Z" ,distance: 1500, time: 6400},
{start_date: "2022-12-08T04:00:00Z" ,distance: 1000, time: 1300}]
```

I want to add the distance and time values ​​grouping them by the month indicated by the start_date value. For example, if two start_dates have the same month 2022-12-01 and 2022-12-08, how can I add the distance and time values ​​of those two months?

so i get a new array like this:

```
 [{month: 12 ,total distance: 2000, total time: 4900}, 
  {month: 02 , total distance: 1500, total time: 6400} ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `reduce` to group them by month which will give an object like

```
{
  12: {
    distance: 2000,
    month: 12,
    time: 4900
  },
  2: {
    distance: 1500,
    month: 2,
    time: 6400
  }
}
```

and using `Object.values` get the values array of it

```js
let x = [{start_date: "2022-12-05T04:00:00Z" ,distance: 1000, time: 3600},{start_date: "2022-02-07T04:00:00Z" ,distance: 1500, time: 6400},{start_date: "2022-12-08T04:00:00Z" ,distance: 1000, time: 1300}]

let res = Object.values(x.reduce((acc,{start_date,distance,time})=> {
    let month = new Date(start_date).getMonth()+1
  if(!acc[month])acc[month] = {totalDistance:0,totalTime:0,month:month}
  acc[month].totalDistance+=distance
  acc[month].totalTime+=time
  return acc;
},{}))


console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a object as a dictionary and save a accumulated value of time and distance per month key. Then, reduce all keys to an array with the requested format.

```js
const groupPerMonth = (list) => {

    const extractMonth = (stringDate) => {
        const month = new Date(stringDate).getMonth() + 1;
        return month < 10 ? `0${month}` : `${month}`;
    }
    
    const months = {};

    for (const item of list) {
        const month = extractMonth(item.start_date);

        if (!(month in months)) {
            months[month] = {
                distance: 0,
                total_time: 0,
            };
        }

        months[month].distance += item.distance;
        months[month].total_time += item.time;
    }

    const result = [];

    for (const month in months) {
        result.push({
            month,
            ...months[month]
        });
    }

    return result;
};
```

And test it:

```js
console.log(
  groupPerMonth([
    { start_date: "2022-12-05T04:00:00Z", distance: 1000, time: 3600 },
    { start_date: "2022-02-07T04:00:00Z", distance: 1500, time: 6400 },
    { start_date: "2022-12-08T04:00:00Z", distance: 1000, time: 1300 },
  ])
);
```

Output:

```js
[
  { month: '12', distance: 2000, total_time: 4900 },
  { month: '02', distance: 1500, total_time: 6400 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be different solutions to this, but one way to solve this is by using the lodash library to solve this. We can first `group` by month, followed by `mapping` each grouped item and adding the distance and time values in each group using `reduce`:

```js
const list = [
    {start_date: "2022-12-05T04:00:00Z" ,distance: 1000, time: 3600},
    {start_date: "2022-02-07T04:00:00Z" ,distance: 1500, time: 6400},
    {start_date: "2022-12-08T04:00:00Z" ,distance: 1000, time: 1300}
]

const grouped = _.groupBy(list, item => {
    const date = new Date(item.start_date)
    return date.getMonth() + 1
})
const groupedAndMapped = _.map(grouped, function(groupedList, date){
    return {
        month: date,
        total_distance: _.reduce(groupedList, (total, current) => {
            return total + current.distance
        }, 0),
        total_time:_.reduce(groupedList, (total, current) => {
            return total + current.time
        }, 0)
    }
})
```

One improvement you could do is to format the month to an `"MM-YYYY"` format or something similar as its possible your data set can include items with different years.